# Has anyone gotten the Orange3 Prototype Widget "Significant Groups" to work?

Tags: orange

The Prototype Widget ["Significant Groups"](https://github.com/biolab/orange3-prototypes/blob/master/orangecontrib/prototypes/widgets/owsignificantgroups.py) would be a great help in hypothesis testing. **Has anyone gotten it running???** I have tried just about everything. Whenever I try to "Compute", I get the pictured error.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've tried it and it works for me. The problem might be with your version of Orange, it being too old. Perhaps update Orange and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I wasn't logged in when I first asked this question. I am now using the most current version of orange canvas available when installed via the 64 bit Miniconda installer. Prior to installing the Miniconda version, I had tried updating all relevant packages via pip, and was using Orange Canvas 3.8. The resulting error remains. If anyone can get this Prototype to work in Orange Canvas (i.e. using one of the add-on datasets) please share an image of what the pipeline and results look like, and state what version of Orange Canvas is being used. Many thanks in advance and best regards!

Comment: Version 3.8.x is too old. Should be at least 3.9+.